# Case statement: WHEN date is more than 90 years from current year THEN max date out at 90 years from current date

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date column that contains people's birthdays. Some of them contain dates that are over 90 years ago and I want those to be capped at 90 years ago.

Example

```
current      desired
1930-01-01   1932-01-01
1930-02-11   1932-02-11
```

As you can see the desired state is to have the birthdate be 90 years from current date if it is naturally over 90 years ago.

Comment: What about 1930-04-01? That would be a 90th birthday still unmarked in the current year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's more tricky than I initially guessed, and it can be written more simpler, now that there seems "be competition", albeit, this is less readable, than it was"

### The no date over 90 years version:

```
SELECT column1 as "current"
    ,iff(column1 < dateadd('year',-90, CURRENT_DATE), 
         date_from_parts(
            year(CURRENT_DATE) - 90 + (month(column1)*100+day(column1) < month(CURRENT_DATE)*100 + day(CURRENT_DATE))::int, 
             month(column1), 
             day(column1)), 
         column1
        ) as desired
FROM VALUES 
    ('1934-01-01'::date),
    ('1932-03-28'::date),
    ('1932-03-20'::date),
    ('1931-03-28'::date),
    ('1931-03-20'::date),
    ('1930-01-01'::date),
    ('1930-02-11'::date);
```

| current | DESIRED |
| --- | --- |
| 1934-01-01 | 1934-01-01 |
| 1932-03-28 | 1932-03-28 |
| 1932-03-20 | 1933-03-20 |
| 1931-03-28 | 1932-03-28 |
| 1931-03-20 | 1933-03-20 |
| 1930-01-01 | 1933-01-01 |
| 1930-02-11 | 1933-02-11 |

### The no year prior to the 90 years ago (aka the title) version:

```
SELECT column1 as "current"
    ,iff(year(column1) < year(CURRENT_DATE)-90, date_from_parts(year(CURRENT_DATE)-90, month(column1), day(column1)), column1) as desired
FROM VALUES
    ('1934-01-01'::date),
    ('1932-03-28'::date),
    ('1932-03-20'::date),
    ('1931-03-28'::date),
    ('1931-03-20'::date),
    ('1930-01-01'::date),
    ('1930-02-11'::date)
;
```

| current | DESIRED |
| --- | --- |
| 1934-01-01 | 1934-01-01 |
| 1932-03-28 | 1932-03-28 |
| 1932-03-20 | 1932-03-20 |
| 1931-03-28 | 1932-03-28 |
| 1931-03-20 | 1932-03-20 |
| 1930-01-01 | 1932-01-01 |
| 1930-02-11 | 1932-02-11 |

### Only sing CASE:

So as it was asked for in the context of CASE statements, I have written it again (and fixed the year partials) but also left it deconstructed, so the logic can be seen:

```
SELECT column1 as birth_day
    ,dateadd('year',-90, CURRENT_DATE) as ninety_years_ago
    ,year(ninety_years_ago) as ninety_years_ago_year
    ,(month(CURRENT_DATE)*100) + day(CURRENT_DATE) as current_partial_year
    ,(month(birth_day)*100) + day(birth_day) as birth_day_partial_year
    ,case when birth_day_partial_year < current_partial_year then 1 else 0 end as partial_year_correction
    ,(birth_day_partial_year < current_partial_year)::int as current_partial_year_alt_version /* not used just showing how it works */
    ,case
        WHEN column1 < ninety_years_ago then
            date_from_parts(ninety_years_ago_year + partial_year_correction, month(birth_day), day(birth_day))
        ELSE 
            birth_day
        END as desired
FROM VALUES 
    ('1934-01-01'::date),
    ('1932-04-28'::date),
    ('1932-03-20'::date),
    ('1931-04-28'::date),
    ('1931-03-20'::date),
    ('1930-01-01'::date),
    ('1930-02-11'::date);
```

gives:

| BIRTH_DAY | NINETY_YEARS_AGO | NINETY_YEARS_AGO_YEAR | CURRENT_PARTIAL_YEAR | BIRTH_DAY_PARTIAL_YEAR | PARTIAL_YEAR_CORRECTION | CURRENT_PARTIAL_YEAR_ALT_VERSION | DESIRED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1934-01-01 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 101 | 1 | 1 | 1934-01-01 |
| 1932-04-28 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 428 | 0 | 0 | 1932-04-28 |
| 1932-03-20 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 320 | 1 | 1 | 1933-03-20 |
| 1931-04-28 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 428 | 0 | 0 | 1932-04-28 |
| 1931-03-20 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 320 | 1 | 1 | 1933-03-20 |
| 1930-01-01 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 101 | 1 | 1 | 1933-01-01 |
| 1930-02-11 | 1932-03-31 | 1932 | 331 | 211 | 1 | 1 | 1933-02-11 |

Comment: I think he need year part only, so `SELECT column1 as "current", year(column1) as year_cur, year(dateadd('year',-90, current_date())) as year_90, iff(year_cur > year_90, year_cur, year_90) as year_new, date_from_parts(year_new, month(column1), day(column1)) as corrected` will be enough. But your solution is perfect.

Comment: yes, a prior edit was simple like that, I just didn't like it.. But yes as a never 91 years ago, that form works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It was sure tricky one. I even checked date diff for 90 years max at timeanddate.com - looks ok. Do appreciate feedback if anyone finds issue in this.

```
select iff(extract(year,dateadd('year',90,column1::date))>extract(year,'2022-02-28'::date),
    column1,
    dateadd(day,
    datediff(day,column1::date,dateadd(year,-90,'2022-02-28'::date)),
    column1::date
    )) as test
    from
    values
    ('1932-02-29'::date)
    ,('1932-02-28'::date)
    ,('1932-03-01'::date)
    ,('1928-02-29'::date)
    ,('1924-02-29'::date)
    ,('1930-01-01'::date)
    ,('1940-05-01'::date)
    ,('1950-12-01'::date)
    ,('1980-10-01'::date)
    ,('1920-06-01'::date)
    ;
    
+------------+
| TEST       |
|------------|
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1932-02-28 |
| 1940-05-01 |
| 1950-12-01 |
| 1980-10-01 |
| 1932-02-28 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Try it with current date of February 28, 2022 and I think you'll get back February 29, 1932. And a couple of those test dates don't appear right to me.

Comment: With 29 Feb, 1932 - the diff is - "89 years, 11 months, 30 days excluding the end date.". Let me know which other date looks off.

Comment: 1920-06-01 turned into 1932-03-01. I guess that's the only one. Try with a birthday on February 28, 1932 and use a current date that falls on a February 28, 2022.

Comment: 1932-02-28 is the output with current date as Feb 28, 2022 and bday on Feb 28, 1932. Checked on timeanddate - the diff is 90 years. Diff of 1932-03-01 and current date (24-Mar-2022) is: 90 yrs 23 days. In case its needed a bit under 90 or exact 90 then this is not correct.

Comment: My concern is that `add_months()` will stick to end of month in some scenario where it shouldn't and so Feb 28th will turn into Feb 29th.

Comment: Are you suggesting that it can output Feb 29th for a year where there is no Feb 29th for that year - rendering an invalid date?

Comment: Try birthdate February 28, 1931 and current date of February 28, 2022. I think that will pull forward to February 29, 1932. If I could easily test myself I would :(

Comment: I checked for this - With 29 Feb, 1932 - the diff is - "89 years, 11 months, 30 days excluding the end date.". I guess it gets off by a day.

Comment: Removed add_months(), replaced with datediff and adding on days now. Looks fine now for leap yr edge case. Still let me know.

Comment: btw `extract(year,CURRENT_DATE)` can be written `year(current_date)` if you like smaller code.