# CASE STATEMENT: When the birth year is more than 90 years from current date. Replace the year in the date with a year that is 90 years prior

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to develop a SQL case statement that caps all birthdates off at 90 years from the current date.

```
current      desired
1900-03-31   1932-03-31
1907-04-01   1932-04-01
1994-05-16   1994-05-16
```

As shown I need to both identify the rows that have birthdays over 90 years ago, and then also replace them with the year that is 90 years from the current date.

Comment: Wasn't a similar question answered earlier - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609470/case-statement-when-date-is-more-than-90-years-from-current-year-then-max-date

Comment: I need it to be apart of a case statement and the solution given is not translating to use that as part of a table transformation @Pankaj

Comment: So if you cannot make the other questions code fit, why don't you ask "that as your question" "over here I asked this"  I got this code" when I try mash it into my existing code that looks like X" it explodes/badthing, please help.

Comment: Also if there are other details you would like that you make reference to, like "this date is truncated", if you put that into your expected output, and/or if you would like an explanation of the partial results/intermediate steps, again ask for it.